# Inject the same instance of a scoped object multiple times

Tags: android, android-adapter, dagger-2, android-mvp

I have an Activity and its presenter, both being injected with an Adapter. The Activity needs the adapter to set on the RecyclerView and the presenter needs it to call update methods (eg: `notifyItemChanged`) when data is changed.

The problem is that because the adapter is injected twice, the presenter and the activity don't have the same instance of it. I need Dagger to create only one instance of it. However, the Adapter needs the Activity's context and has `@ActivityScope` to prevent memory leaks, which means I cannot also use `@Singleton` scope on it.

Is there something I don't understand? Is there a way to inject the adapter in both classes, without setting it manually with a `setAdapter` method in the presenter or the Activity? Or is there a way to limit the number of instances of Adapter created?

EDIT: Dependency injection files:

```
@Module
public interface MainModule {

    @ActivityContext @Binds
    Context context(MainActivity activity);

    @ActivityScope @Binds
    MainContract.Presenter presenter(MainPresenter presenter);

    // CHILD FRAGMENT
    @FragmentScope @ContributesAndroidInjector
    ChildFragment childFragment();

    @ActivityScope @Binds
    ChildContract.Presenter childPresenter(ChildPresenter presenter);

    @ActivityScope @Binds
    ChildContract.AdapterView adapterView(MyAdapter adapter);

}
```

`ChildFragment`, `ChildPresenter` and `MyAdapter` classes are annotated with `@ActivityScope`.

This is the only way I got it to work and seems wrong to me because ChildPresenter and MyAdapter are only used from the fragment. However, annotating them with `@FragmentScope` threw up error: "may not reference bindings with different scopes". Also, the fragment "provider" and and fragment itself are annotated with two different scopes?

Comment: What's wrong with using `@ActivityScope` for it?

Comment: Nothing, but I can't have this scope and also `@Singleton` to limit to one instance.

Comment: Why do you need to limit it to one instance? Presenter, Adapter, and Activity should all be in `@ActivityScope`&mdash;problem solved. If you want to save some state you can create some `@Singleton Repository` or sth that holds the data etc

Comment: They already all are in `@ActivityScope`. My adapter holds no state, my presenter does. Because the presenter provides data and updates the adapter, it must be the same instance that is updated and shown, that's why I need only one instance.

Comment: I believe you have a wrong impression of scopes. Scoped objects exist once in their scope. If everything is activity scoped there will be only one per activity.

Comment: I didn't know that thanks. I'll check the scopes on my classes.

Comment: @DavidMedenjak See my edit, I got it to work but it seems wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an **MVP** architecture, the **presenter** should only care about business logic. That means the the **presenter** does not know anything about Android stuff and does not contain any Android specific items.

In your case you wrote that your **presenter** holds an **adapter** and calls the `notifyItemChanged` methode on it. This is an Android specific item and should not work that way. The **view** is the one responsible for holding the **adapter** and any interaction from the **presenter** to the **adapter** should happen via the **view**.

What that means for your example:

- the **view** creates and holds one single **adapter**
- the **view interface** provides (and the **activity** implements) a call `notifyAdapterItemChanged`
- when the **presenter** needs to tell the **adapter** that data was updated it calls the **view** `notifyAdapterItemChanged` (and the **view** in turn calls the **adapter**)

*side note: If you need the provide data the other way around (from the adapter to the presenter) I would suggest adding a special adapterInterface to the presenter that you can keep as a weakReference in the adapter.*

Hope that helps and let me know if you have any additional questions...

Comment: I didn't clearly mention it, but my adapter implements my `AdapterView` interface with methods like `notifyXX` so the presenter has no android items. Adapter provides data to the presenter through a callback. But I'll try your way.

Comment: I do need to pass data the other way around, but why the WeakReference? I set a callback when the presenter is bound then remove it when it's unbound, is that ok?

Comment: Yes, that works too. I prefer working with weakReferences when I give out access to the presenter via interface simply because it will not block the GC. But  your way will definitely work as well...